# Django JWT - Allow request with no credential if key in body is valid

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt

I have an endpoint that needs an Access Token for authentication.
Also in this endpoint, there's a serializer UUID field that is not required.
What I would like to do is:

- In case the UUID field is passed in the body, check if this UUID is valid and registered in the Database.
- If it's not valid it'll raise a DRF ValidationError.
- If no UUID field is passed then the request needs to be authenticated with an Access Token.

Is there a way to have this kind of seletive auth verification?

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64496495/djangos-custom-authentication-middleware-authentication-backend

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time I figured out the solution.
I opened the permission to access the view to any user, and inside the post method, I verified if the user is anonymous in order to check the request body keys. In case a valid JWT access token is passed, a user would be found and this would return False. If any of these conditions return True a simple credential error response is given.

```
permission_classes = [
    AllowAny,
]

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        request_token = request.POST.get('token')
        token = Token.objects.filter(token=request_token)
        if token.exists() and token.values()[0]['status'] == 'valid':
            pass
        else:
            return Response(
                data={"Invalid Credentials": "Pass a valid credential."},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
```